# api.video-flutter-live-stream iOS crashes after update to XCode 15 and CocoaPods 1.13.0

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, xcode15

I'm using the [api.video-flutter-live-stream](https://github.com/apivideo/api.video-flutter-live-stream) library and everything worked smoothly and fine until I updated XCode to v15.0 and CocoaPods to v1.13.0
From that moment the app crashes with a HashinKit native error reporting the following:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.haishinkit.HaishinKit.NetStream.lock', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000000000
error: memory read failed for 0x0
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

I don't know what to do...any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you only using that library or are there other libraries also?

I had the same issue but I didn't know which package was causing it. I created a new project added all the packages and ran the project. It gave me the same error. Then I removed one package at a time and ran the project until the error went away.
Turns out there was an issue with the [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package. There is an issue filed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135154).

Anyway, what I did end up doing that solved the error was using the code from this [comment](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2152#issuecomment-1731094108) and appending it on the Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      end
  end
end
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm using a tons of packages :')
I'm going to try your solution immediately, be right back!

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!!!!! I OWE YOU A BEER FRIEND! YOU LITERALLY SAVED ME.
I had to do `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'` but finally it worked!

Comment: Hehe it's nice to know that. Until they get a permanent fix, if you happen to clean the Pods file, you might need to add this code back again to make it work.